# Print Odd numbers using 2 arrays in a function

Tags: c

The point of my code is to print all the odd numbers inputted each array using function.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void printOdd(int arr1[], int arr2[], int s1, int s2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] % 2 != 0) {
            printf("%d", arr1[i]);
            count++;
            if(count<(s1+s2)/2)
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s2; i++) {
        if (arr2[i] % 2 != 0) {
            printf("%d", arr2[i]);
            if(count<(s1+s2)/2-1)
            {
                printf(", ");
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int s1, s2;

    printf("Enter first array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &s1);

    int arr1[s1];

    printf("Enter second array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &s2);

    int arr2[s2];
    printf("Enter first array values: ");
    for(int x = 0; x < s1; x++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr1[x]);
    }

    printf("Enter second array values: ");
    for(int y = 0; y < s2; y++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr2[y]);
    }
    
    printOdd(arr1, arr2, s1, s2);
}
```

These are the expected outputs

Enter first array size: 5
Enter second array size: 5
Enter first array values: 1 2 3 4 5
Enter second array values: 6 7 8 9 10
1, 3, 5, 7, 9

Enter first array size: 3
Enter second array size: 3
Enter first array values: 5 6 10
Enter second array values: 12 41 36
5, 41

Enter first array size: 4
Enter second array size: 3
Enter first array values: 1 2 3 5
Enter second array values: 3 2 1
1, 3, 5, 3, 1

My problem is everytime I input numbers, the result is that there is always a comma at the end, here's my output

Enter first array size: 3
Enter second array size: 3
Enter first array values: 5 6 10
Enter second array values: 12 41 36
5, 41,

[https://gyazo.com/9d544951a3572666a3b6b0dc8620d9cc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHI7H.png)

the link is a picture of expected output and my output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is to print the comma *before* printing your value, and only when `count` is non-zero. The reason is that you never know if there will be a next odd number, but you *do* know when there was a previous one. So you should always leave your output with no trailing comma.

```
void printOdd(int arr1[], int arr2[], int s1, int s2) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s1; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] % 2 != 0) {
            if (count > 0) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", arr1[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < s2; i++) {
        if (arr2[i] % 2 != 0) {
            if (count > 0) printf(", ");
            printf("%d", arr2[i]);
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```